Запятая или тире перед например
"Люди часто делают что-то сгоряча, например, берут ипотеку, не имея остаточного дохода, только для того, чтобы сбежать из-под родительского крыла".
Перед "например" может быть поставлено тире?
Оно будет равнозначно запятой перед "например"? Или тут должна стоять строго только запятая или точно только тире?
Или поставить запятую перед тире, а после не надо?)

Возможны варианты:
(1) Люди часто делают что-то сгоряча:  например, берут ипотеку, не имея остаточного дохода, только для того, чтобы сбежать из-под родительского крыла.
(2) Люди часто делают что-то сгоряча — например, берут ипотеку, не имея остаточного дохода, только для того, чтобы сбежать из-под родительского крыла.
Пояснение
Здесь однородные отношения между сказуемыми, причем второе сказуемое значительно распространено (деепричастный оборот, придаточное предложение). Поэтому запятой недостаточно и нужно использовать более сильный знак (пояснительное двоеточие или присоединительное тире).
